# Use SVG icons for button instead of utilizing font awesome

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a script that toggles a button on/off using a font awesome icon.

I do however wish instead to use a SVG sprite from which I have created and change the color accordingly in CSS, but I am not sure how I can change the html and CSS to reflect SVG.

I need the SVG to work for other browsers too.

Thanks.

```js
$('.favorite').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('favorited');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
 html {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5ccccc 0%, #288080 100%);
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.favorite {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
.favorite:before {
  content: '\f08a';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 9px;
}
.favorite.favorited:before {
  content: '\f004';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="favorite"></button>
</div>
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to color an SVG image through CSS is using the `-webkit-mask-image` property to change the color. An example would be like this.

```
.icon {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(icon.svg);
    mask-image: url(icon.svg);
}
```

However this doesn't support in Firefox browser, if you wish to have a support in multiple browsers, you can use CSS filters instead. But you need to find out the configuration for each color which is quite a work. You can learn more [here](http://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images)

What I usually do and the easiest way to do is convert all the SVG images into font icons which I usually do on fontello.com website. It's easy, more lightweight and a quick solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: that sound like a better alternative to create a font instead, thanks...Would you know I would include various and possible best way to include SVG into my html though? Maybe a snippet of some sort to show how?

Comment: which one do you want to achieve? using the CSS filters?

Comment: I have no idea, but I might go with changing my svg paths to a font instead. I am using glypher at the moment, and it looks like I have to modify the paths to create icons in each font tablets for the alphabet. I have no idea what I am doing though. It seems when I upload my svg file on other sites to modify it doesnt allow me to like glypher, the other sitesit read the file as just one icon, but I have like 20 svg icons though.. :/

Comment: It's because you upload all the svg image as one sprite file, try seperating each icons into individual svg files, then upload it again